# Remove accents in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, sorting, locale

I have an array of strings, like so

```
let array = ['Enflure', 'Énorme', 'Zimbabwe', 'Éthiopie', 'Mongolie']
```

I want to sort it alphabetically, so I use `array.sort()`, and the result I get is :

```
['Enflure', 'Mongolie', 'Zimbabwe', 'Énorme', 'Éthiopie']
```

I guess the accents are the problems here, so I would like to replace the `É` with an `E` all over my array.

I tried this

```
for (var i = 0; i < (array.length); i++) {
    array[i].replace(/É/g, "E");
}
```

But it didn't work. How could I do this?

Comment: Small note: remove the -1

Comment: Try http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

> The **`localeCompare()`** method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.
>
> The new `locales` and `options` arguments let applications specify the language whose sort order should be used and customize the behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the `locales` and `options` arguments, the locale and sort order used are entirely implementation dependent.

```js
var array = ['Enflure', 'Mongolie', 'Zimbabwe', 'Énorme', 'Éthiopie'];

array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: It's even better, the accents are not removed but the alphabetical order is respected. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

JS strings are not mutable. That means that replace doesnt replace on the original string, but returns a new one:

```
for (var i = 0; i <(array.length); i++) {
 array[i]=array[i].replace(/É/g,"E");
}
```

Or shorter:

```
array=array.map(s=>s.replace(/É/g,"E"));
```